# Converter string em parâmetro para arrayToDataTable(varString)

Tags: ajax, asp.net, webforms, google-charts

Olá, estou começando a usar ajax e a API do Google (chart) para criar gráficos.

Utilizo um Generic Handler que chamei de 'ColaboradoresEmpresa.ashx', nele eu faço uma consulta no banco de dados e retorno uma string dessa forma;

```
context.Response.Write(valores.ToString());
```

Os dados que eu recebo vem pro Ajax como uma string (no formato correto do parâmetro que devo passar) da seguinte forma;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha dúvida: 'É possível converter essa string para um array ou parâmetro válido para que a minha chamada a API do Google funcione?' pois da forma que está agora eu recebo uma mensagem de erro dizendo: '**Erro em tempo de execução do JavaScript: Not an array**'

Função Ajax:

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  google.load("visualization", "1", {
    packages: ["corechart"]
  });
$(document).ready(function() {
  var urlH = "GenericHandler/ColaboradoresEmpresa.ashx";
  $.ajax({
    url: urlH,
    type: "POST",
    data: {},
    async: true,
    success: function(Valores) {
      alert(Valores);
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(Valores);
      var options = {
        title: '',
        is3D: false
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('Empresa'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    },
    error: function(data) {
      alert("ERRO: " + data.status);
    },
    timeout: 15000
  });
}); < /script>
```

Código do arquivos .ASHX que retorna a string pro Ajax;

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();
            comando.Connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NOMEDB"].ConnectionString);
            comando.CommandText = "SELECT/CONSULTA NO BANCO DE DADOS";
            comando.Connection.Open();
            string valores = "[['Empresa_', 'Colaboradores'], ";
            SqlDataReader dr = comando.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                if (dr["NOMEFANTASIA"] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    valores += "['" + dr["NOMEFANTASIA"].ToString() + "',";
                }
                if (dr["QTD"] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    valores += dr["QTD"].ToString() + "],";
                }
            }
            if (valores.Length > 0)
            {
                valores = valores.Substring(0, valores.Length - 1) + ", ]";
            }
            comando.Connection.Close();
            context.Response.Write(valores.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: uma pergunta, a variável `valores` do lado do servidor, é um array?

Comment: @EnzoTiezzi é uma string no formato: "[['Empresa_', 'Colaboradores'], ['Cleber', 27000], ['Jonathan', 27000], ['Leonardo', 27000], ]". Não sei como convertê-la.

Comment: Como você obtém o valor dessa `String` no seu servidor?

Comment: @EnzoTiezzi eu faço uma consulta num banco de dados atravésde um arquivo .ashx, concateto e retorno uma string no formato acima e retorno ela pro ajax com um  `context.Response.Write(valores.ToString());` mas você também pode ler isso como `context.Response.Write("[['Empresa_', 'Colaboradores'], ['Cleber', 27000], ['Jonathan', 27000], ['Leonardo', 27000], ]");`

Comment: então, se puder, posta essa parte que você disse que concatena, porque dai podemos tentar resolver de maneira que já venha a informação correta, ou pelo menos a mais correta possível.

Comment: @EnzoTiezzi postei o código, também tentei criar um vetor com o Ajax mas ele acusa "0x800a03f6 - Erro em tempo de execução do JavaScript: Caractere inválido". Código: var vet = JSON.parse(Valores);
                    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(vet);

Comment: beleza, agora vamos arrumar isso, tem que ser arrumado pelo lado do servidor mesmo, vamos la

Comment: vamos fazer uma tentativa, a variável `valores` vai se tornar uma `List<string> valores = new List<string>();` e você já colocar ali o valor que quer nela, `valores.Add("['Empresa_', 'Colaboradores']");`, esse é o primeiro passo

Comment: @EnzoTiezzi deixei o código assim: `comando.Connection.Open();List<string> valores = new List<string>();valores.Add("[['Empresa_', 'Colaboradores']");SqlDataReader dr = comando.ExecuteReader();while (dr.Read())
            {if (dr["NOMEFANTASIA"] != DBNull.Value && dr["QTD"] != DBNull.Value){valores.Add(",['" + dr["NOMEFANTASIA"].ToString() + "'," + dr["QTD"].ToString() + "]");}} valores.Add(", ]");
            comando.Connection.Close();`

Comment: faz uma variável `String valor` e dentro de seus `ifs`, substitui a variável `valores` por `valor` e no fim do seu `while` acrescenta  `valores.Add(valor);` e `valor = String.Empty;`

Comment: @EnzoTiezzi fiz isso e executei com um alert(Valores); pra ver como ele retornaria. Retornou no alert um **System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]** mas ainda continua com o erro _Unhandled exception at line 181, column 38 in https://www.google.com/uds/api/visualization/1.0/4e64ac79740513f5765562c361042389/format+pt_BR,default+pt_BR,ui+pt_BR,corechart+pt_BR.I.js 0x800a139e - Erro em tempo de execução do JavaScript: Not an array_ ao tentar definir o valor da variável _data_ no Ajax

Comment: da uma olhada se no lado do servidor, a lista está com os valores desejados.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18617/discussion-between-enzo-tiezzi-and-cleber-teixeira).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz um teste utilizando esses links e consegui utilizar o Generic Handler utilizando essa biblioteca

https://github.com/zoranmax/GoogleDataTableLib

e o código disponível no docs do google chart (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example)

outra resposta:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363721/how-to-create-the-google-datatable-json-expected-source-using-c

Código aspx

```
<head runat="server">
<title>Teste Google Chart</title>

<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "chartData.ashx",
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;

  // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
}

</script>
```

Código ashx

```
using Google.DataTable.Net.Wrapper;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TesteGoogleChart
{
    /// 
    /// Summary description for chartData
    /// 
    public class chartData : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

            List funcs = new List();

            funcs.Add(new Funcioanrios { Nome = "Araujo", Salario = 550 });
            funcs.Add(new Funcioanrios { Nome = "Araujo a", Salario = 500 });
            funcs.Add(new Funcioanrios { Nome = "Araujo b", Salario = 400 });
            funcs.Add(new Funcioanrios { Nome = "Araujo c", Salario = 350 });
            funcs.Add(new Funcioanrios { Nome = "Araujo d", Salario = 300 });
            funcs.Add(new Funcioanrios { Nome = "Araujo e", Salario = 250 });

            var dt = new Google.DataTable.Net.Wrapper.DataTable();
            dt.AddColumn(new Column(ColumnType.String, "Nome", "Nome"));
            dt.AddColumn(new Column(ColumnType.Number, "Salario", "Salario"));

            foreach (var item in funcs)
            {
                Row r = dt.NewRow();
                r.AddCellRange(new Cell[]
                {
                    new Cell(item.Nome),
                    new Cell(item.Salario)
                });
                dt.AddRow(r);
            }

            //Let's create a Json string as expected by the Google Charts API.
            context.Response.Write(dt.GetJson());

        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }


    public class Funcioanrios
    {
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public decimal Salario { get; set; }
    }

}
```